# Can a door button be pushed with anything other than a ball?

Tags: smash-hit

In Smash Hit, at the end of each section in a game, a door can be opened by hitting all the blue circle buttons with a ball, as seen in this screenshot:

[image: door in Smash Hit; above it is a blue circle supposed to be a switch.]

However, curiosity is getting the better of me. **Is it possible to push this switch using anything *other* than a ball?**

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question... you can not. It has to be with a ball (I tested this) so, no. You are unable to open doors without balls.

Comment: Hm. Is there any other source out there that you can use to validate your answer?